# sonarqube - can't access via vscode/curl but works on browser and scanner

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, sonarqube

I'm trying to use VScode with Sonarqube but it shows this error when setting up the connection:

```
http://localhost:9000
Incorrect URL or server is not available
```

It's strange because I can open this URL in browser fine and the `sonar-scanner` works fine with this seeting:

```
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
```

So I made another test: `curl -i localhost:9000` and it returns this error:

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

I'm using Sonarqube on Laradock (laravel + docker compose).

Am I doing something wrong?